# Bibliography with biblatex/biber: Order of names and surnames / Keyword in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I'm trying to format my bibliography for a paper and I have two problems. Here's my minimal code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage,]{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear, isbn=false, doi=false, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=999, mergedate=false, innamebeforetitle, dashed=false, autocite=footnote, mincrossrefs=1, autopunct=false, urldateusetime=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur/literatur.bib}
\setlength{\bibinitsep}{.5\baselineskip}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[nottype=online,heading=bibintoc,title={Literaturverzeichnis}]

\end{document}
```

(I added `\nocite{*}` only for this example). Content of literatur.bib:

```
@book{Bass1985,
    address = {New York},
    author = {Bernard M. Bass},
    publisher = {Free Press},
    title = {Leadership and performance beyond expectations},
    year = {1985},

@article{Bruggenkamp2021,
    author = {Br{\"u}ggenkamp, J{\"o}rg and Preuss, Peter},
    journal = {Wissensmanagement},
    number = {2},
    pages = {46--48},
    title = {Der neue Scrum Guide: Alle Neuerungen im {\"U}berblick},
    volume = {3},
    year = {2021},
```

The article with multiple authors is added like this in the bibliography:

> Brüggenkamp, Jörg und Peter Preuss (2021): Der neue Scrum Guide: Alle
> Neuerungen im Überblick. In: *Wissensmanagement* 3.2 (2021), S. 46–48

Here's the questions:

I'd like to chance the output of multiple authors, so that every author is referenced to with "Name, Surname", multiple authors separated by commas. So the output for the example would be:

> Brüggenkamp, Jörg, Preuss, Peter (2021): Der neue Scrum Guide: Alle
> Neuerungen im Überblick. In: *Wissensmanagement* 3.2 (2021), S. 46–48

In addition my university demands us to add a keyword into the brackets right before the publication date, so the final example would look like that:

> Brüggenkamp, Jörg, Preuss, Preuss (Scrum, 2021): Der neue Scrum Guide:
> Alle Neuerungen im Überblick. In: *Wissensmanagement* 3.2 (2021), S.
> 46–48

Does anyone know a way to add such a keyword here and where to enter that keyword in the .bib file please?

Comment: Please ask only about one thing per question. That makes your question easier to answer and more relevant for future visitors. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864.

Comment: For your first issue you need `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864.

Comment: For the "keyword" thing I don't immediately know a good Q&A on this site, but it reminds me of FOM style. So maybe https://github.com/andygrunwald/FOM-LaTeX-Template helps already.

Comment: Sorry about the two questions, will keep that in mind for future posts. All the more thanks a lot for your answers, the \DeclareNameAlias worked perfectly. I'll have a look at the LaTeX template by Andy, perhaps he had a solution!

Comment: The template has a solution (or at least it had a solution a while ago, when I looked at it), because FOM style requires it (or at least it did at that point). Due to the additional (sometimes quite odd) FOM requirements, I can only recommend the template if you need to hand in your work at FOM. If you don't study at FOM, but just happen to need a similar style, I'd definitely recommend you look for a more stable solution. So do you need this for FOM?

Comment: I'm not, but I found a solution in the template. Thanks a lot!